# Cufon colour stays same after class removal

Tags: jquery, cufon

I have links and when one is clicked there is an id added which changes the colour. The other links have the class removed so there colour will retun to normal. This is working with javascript disabled and I can even see the code working in firebug but for some reason cufon keeps the selected class colour. Any help please. Ta

Answer (score 1):

Try to repaint the text

```
Cufon.refresh();
```

Comment: well Cufon.refresh() refreshes all cufoned elements, so it's a bit slow. Rather select the color-changed elements only, and do a Cufon.replace() again, it's way faster!

Answer (score 1):

Following up on what balint said, here's a jquery example on how to refresh cufon for list elements that toggle classes:

```
$("ul li").click(function(){
    var me = $(this)
    me
        .addClass('active')
        .siblings().removeClass('active')

    // Need to call the function twice for some reason
    Cufon.replace(me);
    Cufon.replace(me.siblings());
})
```

Comment: Won't work right if you use multiple cufon fonts on your page and used another font at last after this one. Cufon.replace uses the last font used if font isn't defined as an option.